# How to access config files when running sbt-assembly'ed application?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am currently using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to make my Scala project into a jar.

In this program I have multiple config files:

```
\root    
    aws.properties
    \src
        \resource
            application.conf
```

There is no problem when program running with sbt or an IDE.

However when I make it as a jar, the application can't find the config files, so that something can't start up.

Is there a way to tell `sbt-assembly` where the file is?

### Update

Here is how I tried to get access to config files:

```scala
val configPath: String = ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("aws").getString("configFile")
val regionName = ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("aws").getString("region")
val credentialFile: File = new File(credentialFilePath)
val credentials: AWSCredentials = new PropertiesCredentials(credentialFile)
```

Comment: show code example of how you access the conf files

Comment: why not put aws.config in resource folder ?

Comment: Please add your build files - `build.sbt` and/or `project/*.scala` - and the error message or even better - upload your project to GitHub to clone and play with.

Answer (score 0):

When you assemble your application, unpack it to see its content. Any discrepancies in the locations of the files could likely be resolved with [assembledMappings](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/src/main/scala/sbtassembly/Plugin.scala#L25).

Comment: Your assembledMappings link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had my `AwsCredentials.properties` file in `src/main/java`. This worked fine when I ran `sbt-assembly` from my eclipse project folder.

However, when I ran `sbt-assembly` on another machine with no eclipse, it wasn't putting `AwsCredentials.properties` into the fat jar.

So I moved `AwsCredentials.properties` into `src/main/resources`, and that fixed it.